# What is more optimal, store parameter and pass to function or pass to function with call to parameter

Tags: c++

New to C++ and trying to learn optimization techniques, so hopefully someone can clarify for me.

Is there a real difference between these two options:

**1) Store parameters and pass to function**

```
const char *text = getText(var)
doSomething(text);
```

**2) Pass to function calls for parameters**

```
doSomething(getText(var));
```

I am not trained enough in computer science to realize the difference when it gets to the compiler stage, unfortunately, so any help would be great!

Comment: For simple micro-optimisations like this: if it makes any difference, and doesn't change the program's observable behaviour, the compiler is already doing it for you. Focus on keeping the code staightforward and readable, using efficient algorithms, and measuring to identify bottlenecks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a technical difference: In

```
doSomething(getText(var));
```

the argument to `doSomething` is an rvalue, while in

```
doSomething(text);
```

The argument is an lvalue. However, in the vast majority of all cases this is irrelevant, and both lines should result in equivalent machine code on any decent compiler, so choose whatever you find to be more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `text` is only used to call to `doSomething()`, the compiler will certainly produce identical code in both cases.

The only difference really is how you perceive the readability between the two and how easy it is in a debugger to stop between `getText()` and `doSomething()`, in case that's necessary.